# Get text back in Summernote on back button

Tags: javascript, html, back-button, summernote

I am new to summer note and using four editors in my webpage (python flask based). I am able to take text from summernote to next page on click of next button but when I click on BACK button(in next page), all the data in summernote goes away. I am looking for a way to retain/load data in editor when coming back from submitted page.
I have another two simple text box (Prepared By & Reviewed By) in the same page and in that I am able to get data because on back button, I am using onclick="storedata().

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the solutions.

```
$(document).ready(function() {              
                $('#topleft').summernote('code', $('#topleft').val());
                $('#topright').summernote('code', $('#topright').val());
                $('#botleft').summernote('code', $('#botleft').val());
                $('#botright').summernote('code', $('#botright').val());
            });
```